# Questions regarding statements about non open sets in general topological space

Tags: general-topology

I would like to ask how do I prove the following two statements in the context of general topological space and also whether one can be deduce from the other.

(1) A set $A$ is not an open set if and only if $\partial A \not\subset A^{c}$

(2) A set $A$ is not an open set if and only if $A \not\subset \mathring A$

Thank you in advance

Comment: I assume $A^{c}$ denoted complement, and $\mathring A$ denotes interior. None of the two questions feels like it should be particularly difficult. Did you try anything, what did you try? What are your definitions of open set, boundary $\partial A$, and interior? Please show anything that you have attempted.

Comment: @Mirko The definition I used are what is described in the definition of the three axioms for a topological space.  I know that for (1) if a set $A$ is not open then $A's$ boundary and $A's$ interior has non empty intersection. Since $A \cap  A^{c}=\varnothing$ and $\partial A \cap A\neq\varnothing$, because $\mathring A \subset A$, then $\partial A \not\subset A^{c}$

Comment: @Mirko Conversely, if $\partial A \not\subset A^{c}$, we then have $\partial A \cap  A^{c}=\varnothing.$ This implies $\partial A \subset  A,$ therefore $\partial A \cap  A\neq\varnothing$.  Hence $A$ is not an open set.

Comment: @Mirko for (2). In one direction, if $A$ is not an open set, I am not sure if I can say the followig:  $\mathring A$ is the largest open set contained in $A$, and $A$ being not an open set, this means there exists an element $x \in A$ that is not in any open sets contained in $A$, in particular $x \not\in \mathring A$

Comment: @Mirko for the converse direction of (2) I am not sure if I can conclude that $\partial A \cap \mathring A\neq\varnothing$ from $A \not\subset \mathring A$, because if $x \in A$ and $x \not\in\mathring A$ then $x$ must be in $\partial A$

Comment: A's boundary and A's interior always have empty intersection. The three axioms describe topology (if I correctly guess which three axioms),they do not describe boundary and interior. Some of what you wrote seems right,but I am lost,given we do not know which definitions we follow. Perhaps you meant a set is not open if it intersects its boundary, then what is the definition of boundary? For the interior, are you taking it by definition to be the largest open set contained in A? Also, you could edit your question please, to include definitions,and your work,so others could more easily answer it

Comment: @Mirko, I am a bit confused here.  The theorems for open sets lije: a set is open if and only if it's boundary is a subset of the set's complement. Also a set is open if and only if it equals to its own interior.  These theorems, similarly for closed sets only apply to metric space topology?  What about if we define topologies based on neighbourhood of a set definition.  The reason I asked because I made another post previously asking what properties can be inferred if we assume a set is not open but at the same time not closed.

Comment: I thought the three axioms for topology: Union of any family of open sets is open. Intersection of any finite family of open sets is open. The whole space and the empty set are open. Now, you say a set is open iff it equals its interior. Well, then it is not open iff it does not equal its interior, which is a proof of your statement (2) from your question. (Note that we always have $\mathring A\subset A$ so if $A \subset\mathring A$ then $A=\mathring A$. Also, $P\iff Q$ is logically equivalent to $\neg P\iff\neg Q$ (where $\neg$ stands for negation). How do you define boundary,interior?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99127/discussion-between-seth-mai-and-mirko).

Comment: @Mirko I am not sure if I actually need to show it, that is if $A$ is not an open set, then $A \not\subset \mathring A$ even though by definition of the interior of a set, $\mathring A \subset A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition $\partial A=\overline A \cap \overline {A^c}.$

Q(1), part 1:

$\partial A\not \subset A^c \implies \exists p\in (\overline A\cap \overline {A^c})\setminus A^c$

$ \implies \exists p\in \overline {A^c}\setminus A^c$

$ \implies \overline {A^c}\ne A^c$ $ \implies A^c$ is not closed

$\implies A$ is not open.

Q(1), part 2:

$A$ is not open $\implies \exists p\in A \,($ No nbhd of $p$ is a subset of $A\,)$

$\implies \exists p \in A \,($ Every nbhd of $p$ intersects $A^c\,)$

$\implies \exists p\in A \,(p\in \overline {A^c})$

$\implies \exists p\in A\cap \overline {A^c}=(A\cap \overline A)\cap \overline {A^c}=A \cap (\overline A \cap \overline {A^c})=A \cap \partial A$

$\implies A \cap \partial A \ne \emptyset $

$\implies \partial A \not \subset A^c.$

Remark: In any space $X$ and any $A\subset X,$ the sets $A^o, (A^c)^o, \partial A$ are pair-wise disjoint and their union is $X.$ Some people write $Fr (A)$ ("Frontier") for $\partial A.$

Comment: Each "$\implies$" occurring in Q(1),part 2 can validly be replaced by "$\iff$" to give a complete A to Q(1).

Comment: thank you for the solution.  Can I ask, for (2),  if I assume that $A$ is not open, how can I show that $A \not\subset\mathring A$?

Comment: $A^o=\cup B$ where $B$ is the set of all open subsets of $A,$ so $A^o\subset  A$...   Hence $A\subset A^o\implies$ $ A\subset A^o\subset A$ $\implies A=A^o \implies A$ is open [being equal to the open set $A^o$]... Turning this around, we have: $A$ is not open$\implies A\not\subset A^o$... BTW we also have ($\overline A\setminus A= \partial A$ iff $A$ is open).